# How do I listen to changes in the size of a ViewPart in an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'd like to add a listener of some sort to a TreeViewer with one column, so that it can know when the ViewPart that it is in is made wider or narrower, and therefore change the width of the one column in the TreeViewer to match the width of the ViewPart it is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when creating ViewPart:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

    parent.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(final ControlEvent e) {
            System.out.println("RESIZE");
        }
    });
}
```